# How to efficiently check updated_at and created_at equality on a set of records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Let's say we have 10 records of a `Post` model, that have the DateTime attributes `updated_at` and `created_at`.

I would like to know which of the following three states is correct:

A. All posts are untouched since creation
B. All posts have been updated since creation
C. Some of the posts have been updated and some untouched

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are unable to update the database, you can create several scopes:

```
scope :changed, where('updated_at > created_at')
scope :unchanged, where('updated_at = created_at')

# Return +true+ if any Posts changed
def self.changed?
  changed.any?
end

# Return +true+ if no Posts changed
def self.unchanged?
  !changed?
end

# Return +true+ if all Posts changed
def self.all_changed?
  unchanged.empty?
end
```

Note that `any?`, `empty?` and `many?` [[source]](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2ad168ee41d590bd9a4d15eddf3c2f719c23b60a/activerecord/lib/active_record/relation.rb#L233-L257) are optimized such that when merged into a scope, they modify the actual sql by using `count(*)` vs iterating over all elements in ruby.  There are some cases where they may fallback to ruby, but typically you will have a more efficient query.

Comment: @yormazar SQL uses a single equal sign for equality.  When the entire `where` is in quotes, it is effectively raw sql.

Comment: just found out that we can also use something like`record.updated_at_changed?` .

Answer (score 2):

if you are looking for a speedy solution my suggest is extra flag `updated:boolean` and `after_validate :set_updated_flag` action

```
def set_updated_flag
  update_attribute :updated, true
end
```

than you can grab it in any way you want, for example with scope

```
 scope :updated, where(:updated=>true)
```

Comment: I like your solution, but suggest you use the `after_update` hook.

Comment: in case of `after_update` hook it is necessary to change `update_attribute` on direct db query or smth. to avoid endless loop

Comment: `> I like your solution...` than you could make +1 to it =)

Comment: Due to a published:boolean attribute (that I hadn't thought of), my original path to compare created_at with updated_at (that Matt Dressel beutifully refined) wasn't reliable, so I ended up with your suggestion together with the Dirty module. Thank you very much!!